# Is it possible to define a function that return a n-dimensional list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wanted to do something like:

```
makeList n
    | n == 0 = [0 ..]
    | n > 0  = repeat $ makeList (n - 1)
    | n < 0  = undefined
```

The code is wrong as its return type is dependent on the value `n`. 
Is there a way that to implement something like that?

Furthermore, I want to construct a N-dimensional list in which every element contains its index, something like:

```
oneD = [0 ..]
twoD = map (\x -> map (\y -> (x, y)) [0 ..]) [0..]
threeD = .. -- hard to code
```

Is there an elegant way to construct a high dimensional list?

Comment: This is two questions in one... the second one has some simple solutions that I'm sure you'd find enlightening, but the first one, if at all solvable, will most probably involve some large-ish singleton-based framework with lots of type-level programming. Are you sure you don't want to split your question into two?

Comment: @Cactus I am very interested in the `type-level` programming, would you please help me split the question, as I am new to haskell and cannot tell the difference between the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In hugomg's answer, we have

```
data RecList a
  = Elem a
  | Dim [RecList a]
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

These do not quite represent n-dimensional lists for some n; in fact, they allow the mixing of lists of different dimensions, as in `Dim [Elem 0, Dim [Elem 0]]`. In Cactus' answer, we have a more complicated type that fixes this problem by exposing the dimension at the type level and forcing all lists to have that dimension; but it uses some quite complicated extensions.

In this answer, we will give a type which is not inhabited by mixed-dimension lists, but which requires no extensions. The idea is simply to track the dimension by giving more constructors to higher-dimensional lists. So:

```
data DeepList a = Z a | S (DeepList [a]) deriving Show
```

Each value will be a Peano nat giving the dimension, followed by a list of that dimension. Thus:

```
Z 0
S (Z [0])
S (S (Z [[0]]))
```

are all values. On the other hand, we simply cannot write something like

```
S (S (Z ["zero", ["zero"]]))
```

as it is not well-typed!

We can construct values of this type. For purposes of testing, I will use `replicate 3` instead of `repeat`, but the idea is the same.

```
makeList :: Int -> a -> DeepList a
makeList 0 v = S (Z (replicate 3 v))
makeList n v = S (makeList (n-1) (replicate 3 v))
```

In ghci:

```
*Main> makeList 2 5
S (S (S (Z [[[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]],[[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]],[[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]]])))
```

Once we have given a `Functor` instance for `DeepList`, it isn't too hard to write your indexed list, either:

```
instance Functor DeepList where
    fmap f (Z v) = Z (f v)
    fmap f (S v) = S (fmap (map f) v)

nD :: Int -> DeepList [Int]
nD 0 = Z []
nD n = S (fmap (\v -> map (:v) [0..]) (nD (n-1)))
```

In ghci:

```
*Main> putStrLn . take 100 . show $ nD 3
S (S (S (Z [[[[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,0],[4,0,0],[5,0,0],[6,0,0],[7,0,0],[8,0,0],[9,0,0],[10,0,
*Main> let S (S (S (Z v))) = nD 3
*Main> putStrLn . take 100 . show . drop 1 $ v
[[[[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[2,0,1],[3,0,1],[4,0,1],[5,0,1],[6,0,1],[7,0,1],[8,0,1],[9,0,1],[10,0,1],[11,0,1]
*Main> putStrLn . take 100 . show . map (drop 1) $ v
[[[[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[2,1,0],[3,1,0],[4,1,0],[5,1,0],[6,1,0],[7,1,0],[8,1,0],[9,1,0],[10,1,0],[11,1,0]
*Main> putStrLn . take 100 . show . map (map (drop 1)) $ v
[[[[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,0],[4,0,0],[5,0,0],[6,0,0],[7,0,0],[8,0,0],[9,0,0],[10,0,0],[11,0,0],[12,0,0
```

Comment: Very nice and makes me look like an idiot for bringing a gun to a knifefight :)

Comment: OTOH, mine can be turned into something like this via an existential, whereas this can't be turned into something that statically knows its number of dimensions... so it's not so clear-cut.

Comment: @Cactus Indeed, these three answers are just three points in the tradeoff space between convenience and strong static guarantees. Which one is "right" depends a lot on what's wanted for the given application.

Comment: A question, if I remove the type declaration of makeList, `makeList :: Int -> a -> DeepList a`, the GHC complain for an error. Why?

Comment: That's because if there's no type signature, type inference assigns a monomorphic type to definitions inside the same mutually recursive group of definitions, and it gets generalized into a polymorphic type only afterward.

Comment: @LiaoPengyu Note that the recursive call has a *different type* than the top-level call. Nobody really knows how to do type inference in the presence of polymorphic recursion [clarification edit: we in fact know that this problem is undecidable]. So Haskell just punts on that and requires you to annotate the types of things which require it.

Answer (score 4):

You can improve the code in @hugomg's answer by adding a type index to `RecList` that tracks the *number of dimenions* in `RecList`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, StandaloneDeriving #-}
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TH

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data RecList (d :: Nat) a where
    Elem :: a -> RecList Z a
    Dim :: [RecList d a] -> RecList (S d) a
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (RecList d a)
```

This way, you will know that `RecList d a` has exactly `d` dimensions.

Here is an example using the [Singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library to reify a type-level index into a term, so we can recurse over it, to make an infinite, `d`-dimensional grid of `()`s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

$(genSingletons [''Nat])

makeNested :: Sing d -> RecList d ()
makeNested SZ = Elem ()
makeNested (SS d) = Dim $ repeat (makeNested d)
```

and here's something closer to your example:

```
makeList :: Sing d -> RecList (S d) Int
makeList SZ = Dim $ map Elem [0..]
makeList (SS d) = Dim $ repeat $ makeList d
```

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem with `makeList` is that you can't easily give a type for it. One of the things you can do is use a recursive type instead of lists of lists. Instead of having a sequence of types `[a]`, `[[a]]`, `[[[a]]]`, ..., you have a single type `RecList a` that represents nested lists with an arbitrary number of levels.

Here is a simplified example using lists of length 1 instead of infinite lists:

```
data RecList a
  = Elem a
  | Dim [RecList a]
  deriving (Eq, Show)

makeNested :: Int -> RecList String
makeNested n
    | n == 0 = Elem "Hi There"
    | n > 0  = Dim [(makeList (n - 1))]
    | n < 0  = undefined
```

Output from ghci:

```
Main*> makeList 4
Dim [Dim [Dim [Dim [Elem "0"]]]]
```

By using a recursive type like this you make the number of dimensions be a value-level thing instead of a type-level thing. It doesn't have the static safety of the type level or metaprogramming-based solutions but its much easier to implement.

Comment: Illuminating, but Daniel Wagner's answer looks more appropriate so I changed the acceptance. Thanks for your answer.